# Tflite model giving different output in Android (ml vision) and Python

Tags: java, python, android, tensorflow, kotlin

I am using ML Vision api to create embeddings from a FaceNet model then comparing cosine distance between two embeddings. The output of Android version and Python differs a lot. Python version is performing way better than android one. What can be the issue? I am using FaceNet model in both.

I am using ML kit for inferencing https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/use-custom-models

I think may be it is caused by the way java reads images as the image array made in android differs with that of same image in python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I was stuck at this problem as I was following google documentation at [ML vision docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/use-custom-models)
Where the image was converted to float array before feeding it to classifier, It looks like this :

```
val bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourInputImage, 224, 224, true)

val batchNum = 0
val input = Array(1) { Array(224) { Array(224) { FloatArray(3) } } }
for (x in 0..223) {
    for (y in 0..223) {
        val pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x, y)
        // Normalize channel values to [-1.0, 1.0]. This requirement varies by
        // model. For example, some models might require values to be normalized
        // to the range [0.0, 1.0] instead.
        input[batchNum][x][y][0] = (Color.red(pixel) - 127) / 255.0f
        input[batchNum][x][y][1] = (Color.green(pixel) - 127) / 255.0f
        input[batchNum][x][y][2] = (Color.blue(pixel) - 127) / 255.0f
    }
}
```

Then I analysed every step one by one found that the way pixels are fetched are wrong and were completely different from the way python does all of it.

Then I found this way of doing it from [this source](https://github.com/lakshaychhabra/android-image-classifier/blob/master/android/tflite/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/tflitecamerademo/ImageClassifier.java) I changed that function with mine:

```
    private fun convertBitmapToByteBuffer(bitmap: Bitmap): ByteBuffer {
        val imgData = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4 * INPUT_SIZE * INPUT_SIZE * PIXEL_SIZE)
        imgData.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
        val intValues = IntArray(INPUT_SIZE * INPUT_SIZE)


        imgData.rewind()
        bitmap.getPixels(intValues, 0, bitmap.width, 0, 0, bitmap.width, bitmap.height)
        // Convert the image to floating point.
        var pixel = 0
        for (i in 0 until INPUT_SIZE) {
            for (j in 0 until INPUT_SIZE) {
                val `val` = intValues[pixel++]
                imgData.putFloat(((`val`.shr(16) and 0xFF) - IMAGE_MEAN)/IMAGE_STD)
                imgData.putFloat(((`val`.shr(8) and 0xFF)- IMAGE_MEAN)/ IMAGE_STD)
                imgData.putFloat(((`val` and 0xFF) - IMAGE_MEAN)/IMAGE_STD)
            }
        }
        return imgData;
   }
```

And it worked!